# Combine results from two machine learning models

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have two machine learning models with one target I run each one alone now am looking to concatenation between both to get one result ...

one of the model it content text with tf-idf and  target and  the another one it content 6 attributes with the target that means all of my data it content 6 attributes so am looking to be in one model

the first one it content two features

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
DTClass = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini", splitter="best", 
 random_state=77)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(bow, 
 df1["attacktype1_txt"], test_size = 1/5, random_state = 50)
DTClass.fit(X_train,y_train)
prediction = DTClass.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print("accuracy score:")
print(accuracy_score(y_test, prediction))
```

and the second

```
array = df.values
X = array[:,1:7]
Y = array[:,7]
 validation_size = 0.20
seed = 4
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = 
 model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, 
  random_state=seed)
    seed = 4
      scoring = 'accuracy'
      models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
       results = []
     names = []
     for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, 
    cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
     results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

Answer (score 3):

*Your problem seems less of an issue with merging models, rather, one with merging data. Unless you have reason to assume that model performance will decrease by inclusion of data, losing information by splitting models should be avoided.*

In this case, it appears the data is a bit chaotic. Perhaps merge to a single `X` array *(I'd suggest doing so in pandas)* and a single `y`. If your `y labels` are not compatible, then you'd want to correct them.

---

***Additionally, I'd suggest reviewing the following tools:***

- [`Voting Classifiers`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) and [`Voting Regressors`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor.html)

  - An extra "hack" is to assign a model's `accuracy` or `f1 score` as the weight in the weighted vote. *This can generate extreme overfitting, so proceed with caution.*
- [`Stacking Classifiers`](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/classifier/StackingClassifier/) and [`Stacking Regressors`](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/regressor/StackingRegressor/)

  - The outcomes of each model in the stack is used as input for the prediction of the final model. *In my experience, this has comparable performance of an optimized `MLP` or `single layer neural network`.*
- [`Boosting`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#gradient-boosting), [`Extreme Gradient Boosting`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html), and [`Light Gradient Boosting`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

  - Each are effective ensemble models which will work in well calibrated "teams" of estimators.