# combining Machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, data-science

Is there is a way to combine multiple ML models where each model use a dataset with different features but same outcome?

I find a way to combine models which is ensemble learning but its only applicable for datasets with the same features

Comment: Take the mean of the predictions.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you have a way to match the entity fields in different datasets (e.g. same id).

Then you can train your models independently and ensemble them in any fashion (bagging, boosting, stacking)

The easiest to try would be a linear combination. E.g.:

- 0.5 * y_pred_1 + 0.5 * y_pred_2
- 0.8 * y_pred_1 + 0.2 * y_pred_2
  [image]

Also refer to:
[similar question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49727557/combine-different-machine-learning-models-into-a-single-meta-ml-model) [similar question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256387/combine-results-from-two-machine-learning-models) [similar question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423696/how-to-combine-two-machine-learning-algorithm-outputs)